# return true for same page validation

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, validation

I am having trouble with a same page AJAX/JavaScript/PHP Captcha validation code.  The original code is from http://www.phpcaptcha.org.  We are using a third party site to store all of our form data into a database that is edited by multiple people.  Lately we've been receiving a ton of spam so we're trying to implement this Captcha.

I'll cut to the chase here.  The code is set to 'return false' every time.  I need it to 'return true' if certain conditions are met.  The code is as follows:

```
<?php
session_start(); // this MUST be called prior to any output including whitespaces and line breaks!


$GLOBALS['DEBUG_MODE'] = 1;
// CHANGE TO 0 TO TURN OFF DEBUG MODE
// IN DEBUG MODE, ONLY THE CAPTCHA CODE IS VALIDATED, AND NO EMAIL IS SENT
// EMAIL is edited out for school use
if( isset($_POST['captcha_code']))
{
$a = array("error"=>0);
print json_encode($a);
}
// Process the form, if it was submitted (Original Code called process_si_contact_form())
process_si_zoho1();

?>
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.0.0/prototype.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
//variables not part of original code
    function reloadCaptcha()
    {
    //original code ElementId labled 'captcha_code'
        document.getElementById('captcha').src ='securimage_show.php?sid=' + Math.random();
    }

    var r, Submit;
function processForm()
{
    new Ajax.Request('<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>', {
        method: 'post',
        //Original code did not state 'zoho1'
       parameters: $('zoho1').serialize(),
        onSuccess: function(transport) {
        //Re-edited for school use. Not original code
            try {
                r = transport.responseText.evalJSON();
                Submit = r.submit

                if (r.error == 0) {
                alert('Congrats!');
                reloadCaptcha();


                } else {

                    alert("There was an error with your submission.\n\n" + r.message);

                }
            } catch(ex) {

                alert("There was an error parsing the json");

            }

        },
        onFailure: function(err) {

            alert("Ajax request failed");
        }

    });
return Submit;
}
}
</script>
```

The process_si-zoho1() is as follows:

```
<?php
//Original code process called 'process_si_contact_form())
function process_si_zoho1()
{
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && @$_POST['do'] == 'contact') {
    // if the form has been submitted

    foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
        if (!is_array($key)) {
            // sanitize the input data
            if ($key != '-------') $value = strip_tags($value);
            $_POST[$key] = htmlspecialchars(stripslashes(trim($value)));
        }
    }

    $captcha = $_POST['captcha_code']; // the user's entry for the captcha code

    $errors = array();  // initialize empty error array


    if (sizeof($errors) == 0) {
        require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/securimage.php';
        $securimage = new Securimage();

        if ($securimage->check($captcha) == false) {
            $errors['captcha_error'] = 'Incorrect security code entered';

        }
    }

   if (sizeof($errors) == 0) {
        // no errors, send the form
       //Edited out mail function from original code

//Changed JSON return array on successful validation to send new variable '$Submit' via serialized $entry
        $Submit = true;
        $entry = array('error' => 0, 'submit' => $Submit);
        die(json_encode($entry));
    } else {
        $errmsg = $captcha_error;
        foreach($errors as $key => $error) {
            // set up error messages to display with each field
            $errmsg .= " - {$error}\n";
            $Submit = false;
        }
//Added $Submit to the return array
        $return = array('error' => 1, 'message' => $errmsg, 'submit' => $Submit);
        die(json_encode($return));
    }


} // POST
} // function process_si_zoho1()


?>
```

The 'processForm()' runs when the submit button is clicked.  I'm sure i'm missing something really simple here, I'm just too involved in it.  I really appreciate your help

I know that the value of 'Submit' is not defined until the PHP in the AJAX.Request() runs but I can't figure out how to define the variable from the start.  FYI, the variables 'r' and 'Submit' are all declared outside the function itself so are global variables.  If I try to insert a return into the try/catch it will always give me the error in the catch "There was an error parsing the json."  Also, with the code as it is now, it will always give me the same error and submit the form anyways, as the value of Submit is blank.  Even if I define the Global variable "Submit" as "false" it still returns as though it is blank.

If anything other than 'return false' is declared at the bottom of the function, it will submit the form without validating the Captcha.  I'm very new to all this, but I've been researching for almost 2 weeks now for 4-8 hours a day and have yet to find a working code.  Is it even possible? I mean, other websites use same page validation and submit to third party databases right?

I can provide more code if needed, but the problem seems to be here.  If I don't try to change the return, the Captcha validates fine and the 'if (r.error == 0)' code executes fine.  I have even added an alert to show the value of 'Submit' just to verify the data is transferring between the functions.

I'm at my wit's end here.  I would appreciate any help.

Thanks,

Matt

The complete code (minus details) is as follows:

```
<?php
session_start(); // this MUST be called prior to any output including whitespaces and line breaks!


$GLOBALS['DEBUG_MODE'] = 1;
// CHANGE TO 0 TO TURN OFF DEBUG MODE
// IN DEBUG MODE, ONLY THE CAPTCHA CODE IS VALIDATED, AND NO EMAIL IS SENT
// EMAIL is edited out for school use

// Process the form, if it was submitted (Original Code called process_si_contact_form())
process_si_zoho1();

?>
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.0.0/prototype.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
//variables not part of original code
    function reloadCaptcha()
    {
    //original code ElementId labled 'captcha_code'
        document.getElementById('captcha').src = '/securimage_show.php?sid=' + Math.random();
    }

    var r, Submit;
function processForm()
{
    new Ajax.Request('<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>', {
        method: 'post',
        //Original code did not state 'zoho1'
       parameters: $('zoho1').serialize(),
        onSuccess: function(transport) {
        //Re-edited for school use. Not original code
            try {
                r = transport.responseText.evalJSON();
                Submit = r.submit;

                if (r.error == 0) {
                alert('Congrats!');
                reloadCaptcha();


                } else {

                    alert("There was an error with your submission.\n\n" + r.message);

                }
            } catch(ex) {

                alert("There was an error parsing the json");

            }

        },
        onFailure: function(err) {

            alert("Ajax request failed");
        }

    });
return false;
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="----------" id="zoho1" method="POST" name="leadForm" onsubmit="return processForm()">
        <input name="----------" type="hidden" value="----------" />
        <input name="----------" type="hidden" value="----------" />
        <input name="----------" type="hidden" value="----------" />
        <input name="----------" type="hidden" value="----------" />
        <input name="----------" type="hidden" value="----------" />
        <input name="----------" type="hidden" value="----------" />
        <input type="hidden" name="do" value="contact" /><br />
        <p>
            <label for="First Name">First Name</label><br />
                <input class="required" maxlength="40" name="First Name" type="text" /></p>
        <p>
            <label for="Last Name">Last Name</label><br />
                <input class="required" maxlength="80" name="Last Name" type="text" /></p>
        <p>
            <label email="" for="">Email</label><br />
                <input class="required validate-email" maxlength="100" name="Email" type="text" /></p>
        <p>
            <label for="Phone">Main Phone</label><br />
                <input class="required" maxlength="30" name="Phone" type="text" /></p>
        <p>
            <label for="Mobile">Mobile Phone</label><br />
                <input maxlength="30" name="Mobile" type="text" /></p>
        <p>
            <label for="State">State</label><br />
                <select class="required validate-selection" name="State"><option selected="selected" value="-None-">-None-</option><option value="AL">AL</option><option value="AK">AK</option><option value="AZ">AZ</option><option value="AR">AR</option><option value="CA">CA</option><option value="CO">CO</option><option value="CT">CT</option><option value="DE">DE</option><option value="DC">DC</option><option value="FL">FL</option><option value="HI">HI</option><option value="ID">ID</option><option value="IL">IL</option><option value="IN">IN</option><option value="IA">IA</option><option value="KS">KS</option><option value="KY">KY</option><option value="LA">LA</option><option value="ME">ME</option><option value="MD">MD</option><option value="MA">MA</option><option value="MI">MI</option><option value="MN">MN</option><option value="MS">MS</option><option value="MO">MO</option><option value="MT">MT</option><option value="NE">NE</option><option value="NV">NV</option><option value="NH">NH</option><option value="NJ">NJ</option><option value="NM">NM</option><option value="NY">NY</option><option value="NC">NC</option><option value="ND">ND</option><option value="OH">OH</option><option value="OK">OK</option><option value="OR">OR</option><option value="PA">PA</option><option value="RI">RI</option><option value="SC">SC</option><option value="SD">SD</option><option value="TN">TN</option><option value="TX">TX</option><option value="UT">UT</option><option value="VT">VT</option><option value="VA">VA</option><option value="WA">WA</option><option value="WV">WV</option><option value="WI">WI</option><option value="WY">WY</option><option value="GA">GA</option></select></p>
<!--<div><label for="Mailing Zip">Mailing Zip</label><br /><input type="text" maxlength="30" name="Mailing Zip" /></div>--><!--<div><label for="Mailing Country">Mailing Country</label><br /><input type="text" maxlength="30" name="Mailing Country" /></div>-->
        <p>
            <label for="----------">----------</label><br />
                <select class="required validate-selection" name="----------"><option selected="selected" value="-None-">-None-</option><option value="----------">----------</option><option value="----------">----------</option><option value="----------">----------</option><option value="----------">----------</option><option value="----------">----------</option><option value="----------">----------</option><option value="----------">----------</option><option value="----------">----------</option></select></p>
        <p>
            <label for="-------">----------</label><br />
                <select class="required validate-selection" name="-------"><option selected="selected" value="-None-">-None-</option><option value="----------">----------</option><option value="----------">----------</option><option value="----------">----------</option><option value="----------">----------</option><option value="----------">----------</option><option value="----------">----------</option></select></p>
        <p>
            <label for="-------">------------</label><br />
                <select class="required validate-selection" name="-------"><option selected="selected" value="-None-">-None-</option><option value="----------">----------</option><option value="----------">----------</option><option value="----------">----------</option><option value="---------">-----------</option></select></p>
        <p>
            <label for="-------">Intended Degree</label><br />
                <select class="required validate-selection" name="-------"><option selected="selected" value="-None-">-None-</option><option value="--------------">-------------</option><option value="-------------">-------------</option><option value="-------------">--------------</option></select></p>
        <p>
            <label for="-------">How did you hear about TTU?</label><br />
                <textarea class="required" height="250" maxlength="1000" name="-------" width="250"></textarea></p>
        <p>
            <label for="Description">Comments</label><br />
                <textarea height="250" maxlength="1000" name="Description" width="250"></textarea></p>
                    <img id="captcha" src="/securimage_show.php" alt="CAPTCHA IMAGE" />
                    <input type="text" id="enterVerify" name="captcha_code" size="10" maxlength="6" />
                    <input type="button" id="reload" name="Reload" value="Reload" onClick="reloadCaptcha()">
                <input class="form-button" name="save" type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
<?php
//Original code process called 'process_si_contact_form())
function process_si_zoho1()
{
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && @$_POST['do'] == 'contact') {
    // if the form has been submitted

    foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
        if (!is_array($key)) {
            // sanitize the input data
            if ($key != '-------') $value = strip_tags($value);
            $_POST[$key] = htmlspecialchars(stripslashes(trim($value)));
        }
    }

    $captcha = $_POST['captcha_code']; // the user's entry for the captcha code

    $errors = array();  // initialize empty error array


    if (sizeof($errors) == 0) {
        require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/securimage.php';
        $securimage = new Securimage();

        if ($securimage->check($captcha) == false) {
            $errors['captcha_error'] = 'Incorrect security code entered';

        }
    }

   if (sizeof($errors) == 0) {
        // no errors, send the form
       //Edited out mail function from original code

//Changed JSON return array on successful validation to send new variable '$Submit' via serialized $entry
        $Submit = true;
        $entry = array('error' => 0, 'submit' => $Submit);
        die(json_encode($entry));
    } else {
        $errmsg = $captcha_error;
        foreach($errors as $key => $error) {
            // set up error messages to display with each field
            $errmsg .= " - {$error}\n";
            $Submit = false;
        }
//Added $Submit to the return array
        $return = array('error' => 1, 'message' => $errmsg, 'submit' => $Submit);
        die(json_encode($return));
    }


} // POST
} // function process_si_zoho1()


?>
```

Comment: Instead of `evalJSON()` Try using `jQuery.parseJSON( json )`. Full docs [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/). Let me know if it works.

Comment: @ROMMEL I'm probably doing something wrong, but it didn't seem to have any effect.  Now, i get the catch error every time.

Comment: There where some security reasons not to use `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`, but I cannot remember right now. Please add the returned json and add what `$('zoho1').serialize()` contains.

Comment: You are using prototype.js?

Comment: @Dirk that's what the original code from securimage called for.  As I said, I'm still pretty new to this, so I've just been trying to debug the code as I went.

Comment: I'm sorry if it sounded like: you should not be using this. That is not what I mean. I was just informing about the framework you were using. You are getting suggestions pointing towards the jQuery library and that won't help in your case then...

Comment: @Dirk I realized after I posted I had not included what I was using, I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the help.  I did some more research, the problem was in the JavaScript (my least experienced portion of code).  I simply added to the:

```
if (r.error == 0)
document.forms['formname'].submit();
```

Thanks for the help guys!  I'll definitely be using this forum again!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 

if( isset( $_POST['captcha'] ))
{
    $a = array("error"=>0);
    print json_encode( $a );
    exit();
}
?>

<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.1.0/prototype.js" ></script>
</head>
<body onload="processForm()">




<form  id="formtest"  action="" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="captcha" value="1vfvrfr">
</form>

<script>

var r, Submit;
function reloadCaptcha(){}
function processForm()
    {
        new Ajax.Request('<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>', {
            method: 'post',
            //Original code did not state 'zoho1'
           parameters: $('formtest').serialize(),
            onSuccess: function(transport) {
            //Re-edited for school use. Not original code
                try {
                    r = transport.responseText.evalJSON();
                    Submit = r.submit

                    if (r.error == 0) {
                    alert('Congrats!');
                    reloadCaptcha();


                    } else {

                        alert("There was an error with your submission.\n\n" + r.message);

                    }
                } catch(ex) {

                    alert("There was an error parsing the json");

                }

            },
            onFailure: function(err) {

                alert("Ajax request failed");
            }

        });
    return Submit;
    }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I'm still having some trouble though.  Now it doesn't seem to be running the script at all.  I don't get any alerts or anything.  I tried editing my script to match yours but continually realized i was missing stuff so I just copied it out and replaced the 'formtest' like you said.  Nothing pops up and it submits the form without validating the Captcha at all.

Comment: Also, I just realized that I hadn't stated that the form is processing as soon as the page loads. That's the very first thing.  It checks the validation that way if the Submit button has been pressed.

Comment: did you include the jquery library? i'll try to work it out on prototype

Comment: Yes, I included the jquery library.  It still seems to do nothing.  As it stands now, both prototype.js and jquery.min.js are included.

Comment: i try your code, and it works well on my end. i'll edit this post.

Comment: the code I am using is from [link](http://www.phpcaptcha.org) I've been trying to modify that code so maybe it would help if we just went back to the original code.  I'm using the example_form.ajax.php securimage.php and securimage_show.php files to generate and validate the Captcha.  I'll post what I have so far, minus any form code.  With your code it's just submitting the form without validating the captcha.  I can submit it without even typing anything or typing the wrong thing.

Comment: i saw the example and it is exactly what you need. can you please provide your complete code.

Comment: I have uploaded the complete code minus a few details.  The details edited out were details the third party site used to upload information to their database

Comment: hey, I figured it out.  Just had to add the document.forms['formname'].submit() in the if/then/else statement.